# how to open a div multiple times corresponding to different button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons which open up the div on click.

What happens: 'form' div opens once, on clicking the button.

What should happen:  'form' div should open up every time a button  is clicked. A 'form' div should open corresponding to a button click.

I researched and found that loop should be used for this (something like putting the showDiv() in the loop)but how do I implement it?

```js
/*For opening search-box*/
$('#click').click(function()
{   
    $("#search-box").toggle();     
});

   
  
/* For opening the form*/
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('booking-form').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#search-box{
 height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background:lightgray;
    display: none;
    font-size: xx-large;

 }
 
 
  #seat{
 height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background:pink;
 font-size:10px;
 
 }
 #booked{
 height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    background:gold;
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;
     
 }
 
 #available{
 height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    background:pink;
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px; 
 }
 
 
 
 .button{
 height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background:pink;
 margin:10px;
 color:black; 
 }
 
    #booking-form{
 height: 200px;
    width: 580px;
    background:bisque;
    margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 15px;
 
 }
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="custom_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>  

   
<!---Font Awesome--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
 <!--font family-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 

</head>  
  
<body>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" id="click" value="Show/Hide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button>
 
    <div id="search-box">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <table>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="1"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="2"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="3"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="4"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="5"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="6"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="7"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="8"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="9"  onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="10" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="11" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="12" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="13" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="14" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="15" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="16" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="17" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="18" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="19" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="20" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="21" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="22" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="23" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  value="24" onclick="showDiv()"/></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</div><!--row div -->

<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" id="booked">Booked</div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5" id="available">Available</div>
  </div>
</div>

</div><!--div grid row-->





<div id="booking-form" style="display:none;">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin:10px;">
    <label for="firstName"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" required>
  </div>
  
  
</div><!--booking form-->
</div><!--search-box-->

  
        
        
 
        
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
     
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!--Custome Jquery-->
<script src="custom_js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean if i clicked two buttons it would show two forms?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the 'onclick' of buttons. To attach the behaviour of call the function `showDiv` when a button is clicked:

```
$('table tr td .button').on('click',function(e)
{   
    showDiv();   
});
```

A selector in jQuery get all elements.

You could also, add a class to know when form is opened, and check with a conditional in click event, which button was clicked with `$(this)`, etc...

**UPDATE**

To add forms, instead of show / close the same, you'll have to append the html code: http://api.jquery.com/append/

**UPDATE 2**

Every time *showDiv* is called, you could clone the `#booking-form` element, and add to a div. I've made a codePen with a working example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNxbmK

*How to make every form has a different id?*

Well, in the click event, you can get the button value with this and pass to *showDiv* function, and change the id before add to `#others` div.

Comment: Can you please tell  how do I implement this in the code above, removing the onclick from all the buttons with this jquery is not working